# lightbox description on the right of the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having an issue trying to change the way the description showing, i don't want it to show below the image because the information in big, so i wanted to show beside the image but it always gives me error, i asked the support of the plug-in and i haven't got any replays i googled but with no luck, i even tried looking for another plug-in which support descriptions on the right of the image but no luck i used this plug-in

> http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/
>
> http://www.sabayafrah.com/secure/

click on any image, the image well expand and the caption well show at the bottom where the user might not know, so i wanted to shift the whole caption to be on the right of the image

update #1
i added  in the css `#imageDataContainer{ floating:right` and it did work but now i wanted to pull it up

Comment: Can you post your amended code? What have you tried already?

Comment: @Barry i tried editing the CSS to show the description on the right but it keeps on ignoring it, i tried change this code `http://pastie.org/1480064` but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Lightbox.css file. The link you posted points to the JavaScript file.

I think you want the image caption to be displayed at the bottom right and the close button on the bottom left? If so, you need to amend the Lightbox.css as follows:

- Change the `float` and `text-direction` properties for `#imageDetails` to right

`#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: right; text-align: right; }`

- Change the `float` property for `#bottomNavClose` to left

`#imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: left;  padding-bottom: 0.7em; outline: none;}`

**EDIT**

These changes will display the caption & close image in the top right hand side - level with the top of the image.

In the Lightbox.js file:

You have to switch round the builder node sections so that the imageDataContainer is at the top. So from line 134 to 163 it should now look this this

```
objBody.appendChild(Builder.node('div',{id:'lightbox'}, [
            Builder.node('div', {id:'imageDataContainer'},
        Builder.node('div',{id:'imageData'}, [
            Builder.node('div',{id:'imageDetails'}, [
                Builder.node('span',{id:'caption'}),
                Builder.node('span',{id:'numberDisplay'})
            ]),
            Builder.node('div',{id:'bottomNav'},
                Builder.node('a',{id:'bottomNavClose', href: '#' },
                    Builder.node('img', { src: LightboxOptions.fileBottomNavCloseImage })
                )
            )
        ])
    ),
    Builder.node('div',{id:'outerImageContainer'}, 
        Builder.node('div',{id:'imageContainer'}, [
            Builder.node('img',{id:'lightboxImage'}), 
            Builder.node('div',{id:'hoverNav'}, [
                Builder.node('a',{id:'prevLink', href: '#' }),
                Builder.node('a',{id:'nextLink', href: '#' })
            ]),
            Builder.node('div',{id:'loading'}, 
                Builder.node('a',{id:'loadingLink', href: '#' }, 
                    Builder.node('img', {src: LightboxOptions.fileLoadingImage})
                )
            )
        ])
    )
]));
```

- On line 303 comment out the following line:

  `this.imageDataContainer.setStyle({ width: widthNew + 'px' });`

Then in the Lightbox.css file you need to change the `#imageDataContainer` to :

`#imageDataContainer{ font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; float:right; background-color: #fff; overflow: auto; width:25%; height:100%; }`

This will then display the image like this:
[image]

Comment: @Barry nope not that, what i wanted is that the caption to show on the right of the image `http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=759&page=1#Item_0`

Comment: @Barry check the link in the question you well understand

Comment: @Barry can they be attached or close

Comment: @Barry is it possible to center the caption

Comment: @Mahmoud - yes just amend the `text-direction` to center in for `#imageDetails` in the CSS file. i.e. `#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: center; } `